# Custom QGraphicsItem deletes itself

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am using PyQt 5.
I have a QGraphicsScene that has a list with QGraphicsObject's to show.
I have no problem with QRectF and other types. However I implemented a custom class as follows:

```
class RobotPathItem(QGraphicsItem):
def __init__(self, path):
    super().__init__()
    qpath = []
    for xy in path:
        qpath.append(QPoint(xy[0],xy[1]))
    self.path = QPolygon(qpath)

def paint(self, painter, option, qwidget = None):
    painter.drawPoints(self.path)

def boundingRect(self):
    return QRectF(0,0,520,520)
```

I then add it to the scene:

```
self.objects[model_obj.id].append(self.scene.addItem(RobotPathItem(model_obj.actuator.get_current_path())))
```

Here self.objects[model_obj.id] is the appropriate list.
It does get shown on the scene.

The problem is that on the very next iteration it is for some reason deleted from the list. If I check

```
print(self.objects[model_obj.id][-1])
```

I get "None" (NoneType). All other objects are still in the list. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out addItem does not return a pointer like addRect or other functions do.
Instead it returns None.

So for the above code to work properly:

`robot_path = RobotPathItem(model_obj.actuator.get_current_path())
            self.scene.addItem(robot_path)
            self.objects[model_obj.id].append(robot_path)`

instead of

```
self.objects[model_obj.id].append(RobotPathItem(model_obj.actuator.get_current_path()))
```

and then implement

```
self.objects[model_obj.id][2].set_path(model_obj.actuator.get_current_path())
```

to update it

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Since addItem takes the pointer you're adding, there's no need to return it, although in this case, it would've been a nice convenience.